# Reading nested json into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `json` file exported from Firebase that looks like the below.

```
{
  "reports" : {
    "Google-Pixel 2 XL" : {
      "-MIoCtD9YUF2G9Esfrfz" : {
        "message" : "04 Oct 2020 23:25:17:047 onCreate MainActivity",
        "timestamp" : 1601825117067
      },
      "-MIoCtFVOxu8wdEHtm6q" : {
        "message" : "04 Oct 2020 23:25:17:214 onCreate Service",
        "timestamp" : 1601825117216
      },
      "-MIoCyBtKMQqQzUHEXsW" : {
        "message" : "04 Oct 2020 23:25:37:682 onStartCommand Service",
        "timestamp" : 1601825137685
      },
      "-MIoFWll9r3qwzWNoGMn" : {
        "message" : "04 Oct 2020 23:36:47:687: (1.3212517, 103.860314)",
        "timestamp" : 1601825807693
      }
    },
    "Vivo 1820" : {
      "-MIoF14JUm6JMZrOzDlL" : {
        "message" : "04 Oct 2020 23:34:37:623 onCreate MainActivity",
        "timestamp" : 1601825677653
      },
      "-MIoF1A9ZZNqTu5W-rQD" : {
        "message" : "04 Oct 2020 23:34:38:016 onCreate Service",
        "timestamp" : 1601825678026
      },
      "-MIoF2gNDua9FfLBTg6q" : {
        "message" : "04 Oct 2020 23:34:44:235 onCreate MainActivity",
        "timestamp" : 1601825684248
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to convert it into a 4 column dataframe that looks like the below

```
model             | id                   | message                               | timestamp
Google-Pixel 2 XL | -MIoCtD9YUF2G9Esfrfz | 04 Oct 2020 23:25:17:047 onCreate...  | 1601825117067
Vivo 1820         | -MIoF14JUm6JMZrOzDlL | 04 Oct 2020 23:34:37:623 onCreate...  | 1601825677653
```

How do I do that? I tried various ways and with normalizing but can't seem to get it.

```
data = pd.read_json("firebase-file.json")
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path="reports")
```

Thank you.

Comment: I would try to do some dictionary comprehension on `test['reports']` to flatten it and name some columns, then you can easily pass the resulting dictionary into pandas via `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to flatten it yourself, good thing it isn't complicated:

```
s = [[k, i, *j.values()] for k,v in data["reports"].items() for i, j in v.items()]

print (pd.DataFrame(s))

                   0                     1                                                  2              3
0  Google-Pixel 2 XL  -MIoCtD9YUF2G9Esfrfz     04 Oct 2020 23:25:17:047 onCreate MainActivity  1601825117067
1  Google-Pixel 2 XL  -MIoCtFVOxu8wdEHtm6q          04 Oct 2020 23:25:17:214 onCreate Service  1601825117216
2  Google-Pixel 2 XL  -MIoCyBtKMQqQzUHEXsW    04 Oct 2020 23:25:37:682 onStartCommand Service  1601825137685
3  Google-Pixel 2 XL  -MIoFWll9r3qwzWNoGMn  04 Oct 2020 23:36:47:687: (1.3212517, 103.860314)  1601825807693
4          Vivo 1820  -MIoF14JUm6JMZrOzDlL     04 Oct 2020 23:34:37:623 onCreate MainActivity  1601825677653
5          Vivo 1820  -MIoF1A9ZZNqTu5W-rQD          04 Oct 2020 23:34:38:016 onCreate Service  1601825678026
6          Vivo 1820  -MIoF2gNDua9FfLBTg6q     04 Oct 2020 23:34:44:235 onCreate MainActivity  1601825684248
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something this (see my comment above)

```py
import pandas as pd


data = []
for k, v in test['reports'].items():
    model_name = k
    for model in v.items():
        _data = {}
        _data['model'] = model_name
        _data['id'] = model[0]
        _data['message'] = model[1]['message']
        _data['timestamp'] = model[1]['timestamp']
        data.append(_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Where `test` is your data, thus `test['reports']` accesses the nested information you want to parse

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) of `pd.json_normalize()`, it assumes an array (list) input. However, the original json is far from something like list of dicts, and most importantly, the key "id" does not exist. Therefore I think a hand-made parser is definitely needed.

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

file_path = "/mnt/ramdisk/in.json"

with open(file_path) as f:
    dic = json.load(f)

# discard the redundant "report" layer
dic = dic["reports"]

# produce a flattened list of dict
ls = []
for k1, v1 in dic.items():
    # k1 = model
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        # k2 = the hash-like id
        v2["model"] = k1
        v2["id"] = k2
        ls.append(v2)

df = pd.json_normalize(ls)
```

**Output**

```
# Trim the message for printing purpose
df2 = df.copy()
df2["message"] = df["message"].apply(lambda s: s[:10])
df2

Out[28]: 
      message      timestamp              model                    id
0  04 Oct 202  1601825117067  Google-Pixel 2 XL  -MIoCtD9YUF2G9Esfrfz
1  04 Oct 202  1601825117216  Google-Pixel 2 XL  -MIoCtFVOxu8wdEHtm6q
2  04 Oct 202  1601825137685  Google-Pixel 2 XL  -MIoCyBtKMQqQzUHEXsW
3  04 Oct 202  1601825807693  Google-Pixel 2 XL  -MIoFWll9r3qwzWNoGMn
4  04 Oct 202  1601825677653          Vivo 1820  -MIoF14JUm6JMZrOzDlL
5  04 Oct 202  1601825678026          Vivo 1820  -MIoF1A9ZZNqTu5W-rQD
6  04 Oct 202  1601825684248          Vivo 1820  -MIoF2gNDua9FfLBTg6q
```

N.B. Going into the layer as deep as where the hash-like `id` locates seems to be necessary. This is because the `id`'s are `keys` originally, but it seems like they have to be reformatted as `values` in order to be correctly interpreted as values by `pd.json_normalize`. My simple survey on the Internet also found no example using a simple built-in method for parsing such a recursive structure.

Comment: I also tried to reuse the existing data structure as much as possible, although it is not clear to me whether this will prevail in benchmarking or not.